# Get minimum value from an Array in a Spark DataFrame column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame with Arrays.

```
val DF = Seq(
  ("123", "|1|2","3|3|4" ),
  ("124", "|3|2","|3|4" )
).toDF("id", "complete1", "complete2")
.select($"id", split($"complete1", "\\|").as("complete1"), split($"complete2", "\\|").as("complete2"))

|id           |complete1|complete2|
+-------------+---------+---------+
|          123| [, 1, 2]|[3, 3, 4]|
|          124| [, 3, 2]| [, 3, 4]|
+-------------+---------+---------+
```

How do I extract the minimum of each arrays?

```
|id           |complete1|complete2|
+-------------+---------+---------+
|          123| 1       | 3       |
|          124| 2       | 3       |
+-------------+---------+---------+
```

I have tried defining a UDF to do this but I am getting an error.

```
def minArray(a:Array[String]) :String = a.filter(_.nonEmpty).min.mkString
val minArrayUDF = udf(minArray _)   
def getMinArray(df: DataFrame, i: Int): DataFrame = df.withColumn("complete" + i, minArrayUDF(df("complete" + i)))

val minDf = (1 to 2).foldLeft(DF){ case (df, i) => getMinArray(df, i)}

java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your `udf` function as below

```
def minUdf = udf((arr: Seq[String])=> arr.filterNot(_ == "").map(_.toInt).min)
```

and call it as

```
DF.select(col("id"), minUdf(col("complete1")).as("complete1"), minUdf(col("complete2")).as("complete2")).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+---------+---------+
|id |complete1|complete2|
+---+---------+---------+
|123|1        |3        |
|124|2        |3        |
+---+---------+---------+
```

**Updated**

In case *if the array passed to udf functions are empty or array of empty strings* then you will encounter

> > java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.min

You should handle that with `if else` condition in `udf` function as

```
def minUdf = udf((arr: Seq[String])=> {
  val filtered = arr.filterNot(_ == "")
  if(filtered.isEmpty) 0
  else filtered.map(_.toInt).min
})
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: This works great!
How do I deal with empty arrays [ ,  , ]?
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.min

Answer (score 7):

Since Spark 2.4, you can use [`array_min`](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions.html#array-min) to find the minimum value in an array. To use this function you will first have to cast your arrays of strings to arrays of integers. Casting will also take care of the empty strings by converting them into `null` values.

```scala
DF.select($"id",
          array_min(expr("cast(complete1 as array<int>)")).as("complete1"),
          array_min(expr("cast(complete2 as array<int>)")).as("complete2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it without using `udf`

First `explode` the array you got with `split()` and then group by the same id and find `min`

```
  val DF = Seq(
    ("123", "|1|2","3|3|4" ),
    ("124", "|3|2","|3|4" )
  ).toDF("id", "complete1", "complete2")
    .select($"id", split($"complete1", "\\|").as("complete1"), split($"complete2", "\\|").as("complete2"))
    .withColumn("complete1", explode($"complete1"))
    .withColumn("complete2", explode($"complete2"))
    .groupBy($"id").agg(min($"complete1".cast(IntegerType)).as("complete1"), min($"complete2".cast(IntegerType)).as("complete2"))
```

Output:

```
+---+---------+---------+
|id |complete1|complete2|
+---+---------+---------+
|124|2        |3        |
|123|1        |3        |
+---+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an UDF for this, you can use `sort_array`:

```
val DF = Seq(
  ("123", "|1|2","3|3|4" ),
  ("124", "|3|2","|3|4" )
).toDF("id", "complete1", "complete2")
  .select(
    $"id",
    split(regexp_replace($"complete1","^\\|",""), "\\|").as("complete1"),
    split(regexp_replace($"complete2","^\\|",""), "\\|").as("complete2")
  )


// now select minimum
DF.
 .select(
  $"id",
  sort_array($"complete1")(0).as("complete1"),
  sort_array($"complete2")(0).as("complete2")
).show()

+---+---------+---------+
| id|complete1|complete2|
+---+---------+---------+
|123|        1|        3|
|124|        2|        3|
+---+---------+---------+
```

Note that I removed the leading `|` before splitting to avoid empty strings in the array

Comment: I do have empty strings in my arrays. Some of them are only have empties.